# Design issue in Iphone Dev - Generic implementation for Game Bonuses

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So, I thought consulting you guys about my design, cause I sense there might be a better way of doing it.

I need to implement game bonuses mechanism in my app.
Currently there are 9 bonuses available, each one is based of different param of the MainGame Object.

What I had in mind was at app startup to initialize 9 objects of GameBonus while each one will have different SEL (shouldBonus) which will be responsible for checking if the bonus is valid.

So, every end of game I will just run over the bonuses array and call the isBonusValid() function with the MainGame object(which is different after every game).

How's that sound ?

The only issue I have currently, is that I need to make sure that if some bonuses are accepted some other won't (inner stuff)... any advice how to do that and still maintain generic implementation ?

```
@interface GameBonus : NSObject {

    int bonusId;
    NSString* name;
    NSString* description;
    UIImage* img;
    SEL      shouldBonus;


}

@implementation GameBonus

-(BOOL) isBonusValid(MainGame*)mainGame
{
    [self shouldBonus:mainGame];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds ok, the only change I would consider is perhaps removing a bonus from the array should it be acepted. That way it is not checked in the future. This would also work for bonus that for other reason should no longer be available.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I think you got me wrong. I do want the player to be able to get the same bonuses at a different game, I just want to make sure that if he gets bonus "4" for example he won't get "3" as well at the same game. for example "4" is "got more then 40 points bonus" and "3" is "got more then 30 points bonus". any suggestion on how to do that with my current implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the player can obtain a particular bonus according to the rules of your game isn't something the individual bonuses would know about.  This is something the game itself would know.  For example, you may have one game that allows bonuses A and B together, but another game that wouldn't.

So the logic to grant or deny a bonus should be in the MainGame object.  I would organize it so that GameBonus is a plain bit bucket class and the logic is all in the MainGame.  MainGame would be a superclass of any other custom games that might want to override the bonus logic.

A starting point:

```
typedef enum {
    BonusTypeA, BonusTypeB, BonusTypeC
} BonusId;

@interface GameBonus : NSObject {
    BonusId bonusId;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *description;
    UIImage *img;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) BonusId bonusId;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *img;
@end

@interface MainGame : NSObject {
    NSMutableSet *activeBonuses;
}

-(BOOL) tryToSetBonus:(BonusId)bonus; // tries to set, returns YES if successful.
-(BOOL) isBonusValid:(BonusId)bonus;  // has no side effect, just check validity.
@end
```

Comment: Well, your solution is not generic at all. let's say I hard code all the bonus checks, then I want to add another bonus, I need to add more code to the MainGame object. (or remove for that matter). in My solution you just add a gameBonus with a specific SEL.In my opinion that's better. The only issue I have is how to make sure that if one bonus is accepted I can deny another.(see my comment to Derek) Thanks for the answer though.